# Browse only mode for Drupal 6

Tags: 6, maintenance-mode

While we do some server maintenance, how might be prohibit our users from editing or adding content but not put the site in offline mode. That is, we'd like to have content browseable but temporarily prohibit content from changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used this module, but seems to do what you want: [Read only mode](http://drupal.org/project/readonlymode/).

Comment: I was so hoping this one would work but, after activating read-only mode I was still able to join organic groups add status to those OGs. I did file a bug report http://drupal.org/node/1717538

Answer (score 1):

This will take some effort to accomplish what you are asking for, but as a high level overview, you could use CTools' panel variants for `user/%user/edit` and `node/%node/edit` or whatever is equivalent in D6. And then you selection criteria as php code and then write some logic.

Not done this myself, but it should be possible this way.

Comment: Very interesting use of page manager. Cool.

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning to see the depth of the issue. The above mentioned module readonlymode seems to block node creation, but in Organic Groups anyway, I'm still able to add and delete information. So, I'm still hunting.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this (seems to be the common thread here!) but [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) has a feature for running entirely without the database. It also has a crawler to ensure pages are cached. Note the warning! [image: screenshot]